# Clear example/documentation of how to use Google login for my web app

Tags: javascript, c++, authentication

I maintain an old web app written in C++ & javascript. I have been asked to add Facebook, Google and Twitter login authentication.

The Facebook bit went well. I found some simple javascript code on Facebook's developer site http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ which I added to my login page. I then altered the C++ login cgi program to recognise callbacks from Facebook, and to log the user in using their email address (which is already held on file).

I'm stuck with the Google bit. At first I thrashed around on the Google site, but I couldn't find any simple examples. I was directed to the libopkele C++ library, but I can't find any instructions on how to use it (and I suspect it is not what I need). Then I found something called Google Friend Connect http://code.google.com/apis/friendconnect/docs/code.html (which, unfortunately, says it is depreciated). That contained a nice javascript example, which I put into my website. It provides a button that says "Sign in", and when you click it, it pops up a window asking for your email address. You fill in the address, it says "Connecting to your IDP", then "Redirecting to your IDP", then my post-login page appears in the pop-up window.

Obviously I don't want that - I want it to appear in the original window where they clicked the "Sign in" button.

Here is my javascript from the login page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/googleapis/0.0.4/googleapis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("identitytoolkit", "1", {packages: ["ac"], language:"en"});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    window.google.identitytoolkit.setConfig({
        developerKey: "<I put my developer key here>",
        companyName: "<I put my company name here>",
        callbackUrl: "http://www.mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/login.cgi",
        realm: "",
        userStatusUrl: "http://http://www.mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/loginstatus.cgi",
        loginUrl: "http://http://www.mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/login.cgi",
        signupUrl: "http://http://www.mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/login.cgi",
        homeUrl: "http://www.mywebsite.com",
        logoutUrl: "http://http://www.mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/logout.cgi",
        idps: ["Gmail", "GoogleApps", "Yahoo"],
        tryFederatedFirst: true,
        useCachedUserStatus: false
    });
    $("#navbar").accountChooser();
  });
</script>
<div id="navbar"></div>
```

I find my userStatusUrl is never called. The callbackUrl is called, but I am not sure what to return from it. It seems whatever I return is merely displayed on the page. I saw a passing reference somewhere to returning a json item containing {"registered" : true}, but that didn't work either (here is the exact text I returned from my cgi script):

```
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 20

{"registered" : true}
```

Any help, or pointers to a nice simple implementation appreciated. (A PHP script that uses external libraries would not be much help!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used [rpxnow.com](http://rpxnow.com), which provides easy to use login via a selection of providers using a single, simple, well-documented  interface.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into Google's OpenID?

> Third-party websites and applications can now let visitors sign in
>   using their Google user accounts. Federated Login, based on the OpenID
>   standard, frees users from having to set up separate login accounts
>   for different web sites--and frees web site developers from the task
>   of implementing login authentication measures. OpenID achieves this
>   goal by providing a framework in which users can establish an account
>   with an OpenID provider, such as Google, and use that account to sign
>   into any web site that accepts OpenIDs. This page describes how to
>   integrate Google's Federated Login for a web site or application.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

Comment: Yes, that's the first place I went. I was unable to find clear, cookbook examples of how to log in using C++ or javascript.

Comment: In the end, I used http://rpxnow.com, which provides easy to use login via a selection of providers using a single, simple, well-documented  interface.